# expected char got number SUM Oracle

Tags: oracle

```
    SELECT
  (
    CASE     
      WHEN  s.weight = '-'  THEN s.weight      
      ELSE SUM(s.weight)
      END
   ) AS weight
FROM
  shipping s
WHERE
  s.id_packing_info = 257834;
```

Hello , I store the weight in database as "-" if does not have to use weight and a number if it has.

When it comes '-' it appears the error

```
**ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 185 Column: 12**  on **ELSE SUM(s.weight)**
```

why ? because it has to enter on THEN not on ELSE.

Comment: What datatype is the weight column?

Comment: This question is unclear: what are you trying to accomplish? Do you want *the sum of all the values that are not a `'-'`*? E.g. if there are 3 values: `'555'`, `'666'`, and `'-'`, do you want to get `555+666`, so `'1221'` as a result?

Comment: @MarcusH OP is using `'-'` as `NULL`, so I assume VARCHAR2 - but definitely not a DECIMAL...

Comment: unfortunately is varchar.  @Marcus H

Comment: there can't be three values like '22' '33' and '-' . It's '-' or values. If is not '-' to sum all the weights from that id

Comment: `there can't be three values like '22' '33' and '-' . It's '-' or values` Then why are you using the `SUM` function?

Comment: if is not "-" to make a sum for the values

Comment: `if is not "-" to make a sum for the values` Then there **are** more than one values, like in my example, right? Nevermind, Please edit your question with **an example** of **what data you have** and **what is your expected output**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate the case expression inside the aggregate sum function:

```
SELECT
  NVL(TO_CHAR(SUM(
      CASE WHEN s.weight = '-' THEN NULL ELSE TO_NUMBER(s.weight) END
    )), '-') AS weight
FROM
  shipping s
WHERE
  s.id_packing_info = 257834;
```

If the ID has only value(s) `'-'` then the case expression evaluates to null, so the sum is null too; that is then NVL'd back to a dash.

If the ID has any 'number' values then the case evaluates to an actual number for those, and the sum works as expected, and is not null. If you have both numbers and a dash (which you said you won't have) then the dash is still evaluated as null but the numbers are still summed up, so the dash is ignored effectively.

Demo with some made up data:

```
with shipping (id_packing_info, weight) as (
  select 257834, '-' from dual
  union all select 257835, '2' from dual
  union all select 257835, '3' from dual
  union all select 257836, '4' from dual
  union all select 257836, '5' from dual
  union all select 257836, '-' from dual
)
SELECT
  NVL(TO_CHAR(SUM(
      CASE WHEN s.weight = '-' THEN NULL ELSE TO_NUMBER(s.weight) END
    )), '-') AS weight
FROM
  shipping s
WHERE
  s.id_packing_info = 257834; 

WEIGHT                                 
----------------------------------------
-                                       

...
WHERE
  s.id_packing_info = 257835; 

WEIGHT                                 
----------------------------------------
5                                       

...
WHERE
  s.id_packing_info = 257836; 

WEIGHT                                 
----------------------------------------
9
```

The explicit `TO_NUMBER()` isn't really necessary but it's making it a bit clearer. The explicit `TO_CHAR()` is needed though, to stop `NVL()` trying to convert the dash to the same datatype as the `SUM()` result, which would get ORA-01722.

That's the same reason you get the ORA-00932 in your original code, essentially. The first branch of your case expression evaluates to a string, so it expects the second branch to do the same; but `SUM()` gives you a number not a string. You might think, then, that you could change it to:

```
CASE     
  WHEN  s.weight = '-'  THEN s.weight      
  ELSE TO_CHAR(SUM(s.weight))
  END
```

but that is mixing aggregate and non-aggregate values, so you'd end up with ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can add one more condition to skip such records

```
SELECT NVL(TO_CHAR(SUM(TO_NUMBER(s.weight))), '-') AS weight
FROM shipping s
WHERE  s.id_packing_info = 257834 AND s.weight <> '-'
```